# Can't create Hello World in Eclipse (Mac), Building error (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I installed Java & Eclipse and wanted to run the tutorial of the Hello World project. 
As soon as I start with the first real step, creating a Java Project, I do everything alike the Tutorial, write the name "HelloWorld", finish.

Then a Window pops up, that wants me to create a new module-info.java. That is pretty strange, I have not seen anything like this in a Tutorial anywhere, but either way, if I create it or not, I get an error:

`Errors occurred during the build.`

`Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'HiWorld'.
java.lang.NullPointerException`

Does anyone know something about this issue?

I have already tried to look in the Properties - Building Path, but when I add, remove, change something I do not get anywhere.
I had the idea that it could be a problem with my eclipse, but I reinstalled it twice already (Java as well) and I have not made any progress.

My code is just:

```
module helloworld {
}
```

I want to eliminate the error, so that later on my HelloWorld program is running. 
Thank you for taking some time!

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this!

Comment: I am sorry for asking, but you do not mean the compliance level? Because I have the opportunity between 11,10,9 and then 1.8

Comment: If I do go to 1.8 for example, I get the error, that no JRE is installed in this workspace. Do I have to install this JRE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the tutorial, but I imagine it's for below Java 9, of which module-info is part.

Go into Eclipse project settings and set language level to 8 (there's plenty of guides online) and you should be good.

Edit: If, however, the tutorial is for Java 9, I'd really recommend finding another tutorial as the module stuff is a whole set of extra complication which you don't need right away (I've yet to see Java 9 used in the real world)

Comment: do you have a link for such a tutorial? I can online find those that modify the compliance level.

Comment: @cruiser0223 there are so many. thenewboston on youtube is good